# How to split the row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

table1

```
value

100 x 200 x 300 x 400  `I want to split this row bcoz more than 2 values`
100 x 200
1300 x 1400
200 x 300 x 1200 x 2200  `I want to split this row bcoz more than 2 values`
....
```

Value column is not fixed length, it may also contain `10 x 200 x 3000 x 5`

I want to take the first 2 values then the next 2 values will go to the next row after `x`

I want to split the rows like this:

Expected Output

```
100 x 200 
300 x 400
100 x 200
1300 x 1400
200 x 300 
1200 x 2200
....
```

**Hint:**

We can split the value for each x then we can join 2 values

for example `20 x 10 x 5 x 1`

Split like this `20, 10 5, 1` then join `20 x 10, 5 x 1`

The above method will work out, if it work out means then can i get some query for splitting and joining the rows..

How can I do this in SQL?

Need SQL Query Help

Comment: What if the column as 3 values instead of 2 or 4? Can it have 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c1cc/4)**

```
SELECT Rtrim(Substring(value, 1, CHARINDEX( 'x' , value, CHARINDEX( 'x', value) + 1) - 2))
FROM (SELECT value
    FROM table1
    Where LEN(value) - LEN(REPLACE(value, 'x', '')) >= 2) as temp
UNION ALL 
SELECT Substring(value, CHARINDEX( 'x' , value, CHARINDEX( 'x', value) + 1) + 2, LEN(value))
FROM (SELECT value
FROM table1
Where LEN(value) - LEN(REPLACE(value, 'x', '')) >= 2) as temp1
```

Comment: can you give some hint for splitting also

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want good solution, then I think you need to create user defined function `split` and then join data again (using `ntile` function for example). If you really want to split only by 2 elements, then you can use such a query

```
select R.value
from table1 as t
   outer apply (select charindex(' x ', t.value) as c1) as c1
   outer apply (select right(t.value, len(t.value) - c1.c1 - 2) as s1) as s1
   outer apply (select charindex(' x ', s1.s1) as c2) as c2
   outer apply (select case when c2.c2 > 0 then right(s1.s1, len(s1.s1) - c2.c2 - 2) else null end as s2) as s2
   outer apply (
       select case when c2.c2 > 0 then left(t.value, c2.c2 + c1.c1 + 1) else t.value end as value
       union all
       select s2.s2
   ) as R
where R.value is not null
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c1cc/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
SELECT CASE CHARINDEX ('x',value, CHARINDEX('x',value,0)+1) 
        WHEN 0 THEN value 
        ELSE RTRIM(SUBSTRING(value,0, CHARINDEX ('x',value,
       CHARINDEX('x',value,0)+1))) END AS newValue
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(value,
        CHARINDEX ('x',value, CHARINDEX('x',value,0)+1)+1,LEN(value))) AS newValue
WHERE CHARINDEX ('x',value, CHARINDEX('x',value,0)+1) >0
FROM table1
```

Comment: Why did you add a CTE when the question is tagged with SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Yep, u r correct, I missed that point. I put it back to original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first your table must have ID.
Let's say ypu have table Numbers like this:

```
NumberID Number
1        100 x 200 x 300 x 400
2        100 x 200
3        1300 x 1400    
4        200 x 200 x 200 x 200
```

Solution is this query:

```
select * from
    (
    select 
    NumberID AS 'NumberID',
    case when  CHARINDEX('X', Number, CHARINDEX ( 'X' ,Number ) +1)  = 0
                then Number
                else SUBSTRING(Number,   0, LEN(Number) -  CHARINDEX('X', Number, CHARINDEX ( 'X' ,Number ) +1 ))
                END AS Result
    from Numbers

    UNION ALL

    select 
    NumberID AS 'NumberID',
                SUBSTRING(Number,   CHARINDEX('X', Number, CHARINDEX ( 'X' ,Number ) +1 )  +2 , LEN(Number) -  CHARINDEX('X', Number, CHARINDEX ( 'X' ,Number ) +1 ))
                AS Result
    from Numbers
    WHERE CHARINDEX('X', Number, CHARINDEX ( 'X' ,Number ) +1)  <> 0
    ) t1
    ORDER BY t1.NumberID
```

Result for this query is:

```
1   100 x 200
1   300 x 400
2   100 x 200
3   1300 x 1400
4   200 x 200
4   200 x 200
```

I believe this is exactly what you looking for.